# ajax post request is completed (status: 200) but it is not adding information to json file

Tags: json, ajax, post

My code is a simple get and post to JSON via jQuery AJAX.
here is the JSON file "drinks.json"

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Will",
        "drink": "coffee"
}]
```

I am able to read data from the json file but when trying to post the data never make it to the json file. here is my post request:

```
 $("#add-order").on("click", function () {  
  var order = {
    id: 3,
    name: $name.val(),
    drink: $drink.val()
  };

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: order,
    url: "./drinks",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(r){
    console.log(r);
  })
});
```

I am using wampserver and I can see the status of the request is 200. I also tried JSON.stringify(order) with no success.

Comment: you mean `./drinks` literally points to a static .json file?? If so you can't write data to it like that using a HTTP request (unless you've left the filesystem permissions completely insecure) - you need a server-side programming language to receive the HTTP request, process it, and write the data to the file.

Comment: If you're already using server-side scripting, then you'll need to show us that code, because the fault is more likely to be there than in the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to directly post the data to json file. Unfortunately you can't do it that easily. You simply can not write files on your server directly by AJAX, but you can do it by creating additional small PHP file and sending there data instead.

```
<?php
   $arrFromJson = json_decode(file_get_contents("drinks.json"), true);
   array_push($arrFromJson, $_POST["newDrink"]);
   // change json accordingly -> var order = { newDrink: { ...
   $newJson = json_encode($arrFromJson);
   file_put_contents("drinks.json", $newJson);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer. Do you think I can use Node.js instead of php ??

Comment: @Amonem of course, you can use any server side language that is supported by your O/S and webserver

Comment: Thanks alot ADyson ... appreciate it